# How do I get Polynote running with Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, polynote

I'm hoping to run [Polynote](https://polynote.org) and in particular against my Kubernetes cluster. Unfortunately I'm not having any luck, the error messages are not particularly helpful, and as far as I can tell it's new enough that there isn't already a reference Kubernetes configuration I can use to make this work.

With the YAML file below I'm getting it to boot up successfully. When I port forward and try to access the pod, though, it crashes the pod, which then restarts and unfortunately the error message I get is literally `Killed`, which isn't super instructive. I started with the bare Docker image, then added the configuration they suggested in [the Docker notes in their repository](https://github.com/polynote/polynote/tree/master/docker).

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: polynote-config
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: polynote
data:
  config.yml: |-
    listen:
      host: 0.0.0.0

    storage:
      dir: /opt/notebooks
      mounts:
        examples:
          dir: examples
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: polynote
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: polynote
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: polynote
        image: polynote/polynote:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "100Mi"
          requests:
            memory: "100Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8192
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /opt/config/config.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: config.yml
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: polynote-config
```

Edit: For clarity, here is the entirety of the logging from the pod:

```
[INFO]  Loading configuration from config.yml
[INFO]  Loaded configuration: PolynoteConfig(Listen(8192,127.0.0.1),Storage(tmp,notebooks,Map()),List(),List(),Map(),Map(),Behavior(true,Always,List()),Security(None),UI(/))
[WARN]  Polynote allows arbitrary remote code execution, which is necessary for a notebook tool to function.
        While we'll try to improve safety by adding security measures, it will never be completely safe to
        run Polynote on your personal computer. For example:

        - It's possible that other websites you visit could use Polynote as an attack vector. Browsing the web
          while running Polynote is unsafe.
        - It's possible that remote attackers could use Polynote as an attack vector. Running Polynote on a
          computer that's accessible from the internet is unsafe.
        - Even running Polynote inside a container doesn't guarantee safety, as there will always be
          privilege escalation and container escape vulnerabilities which an attacker could leverage.

        Please be diligent about checking for new releases, as they could contain fixes for critical security
        flaws.

        Please be mindful of the security issues that Polynote causes; consult your company's security team
        before running Polynote. You are solely responsible for any breach, loss, or damage caused by running
        this software insecurely.
[zio-default-async-1-1076496284] INFO org.http4s.blaze.channel.nio1.NIO1SocketServerGroup - Service bound to address /127.0.0.1:8192
[zio-default-async-1-1076496284] INFO org.http4s.server.blaze.BlazeServerBuilder - 


  _____      _                   _
 |  __ \    | |                 | |
 | |__) |__ | |_   _ _ __   ___ | |_ ___
 |  ___/ _ \| | | | | '_ \ / _ \| __/ _ \
 | |  | (_) | | |_| | | | | (_) | ||  __/
 |_|   \___/|_|\__, |_| |_|\___/ \__\___|
                __/ |
               |___/

Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8192
[zio-default-async-1-1076496284] INFO org.http4s.server.blaze.BlazeServerBuilder - http4s v0.20.6 on blaze v0.14.6 started at http://127.0.0.1:8192/
Killed
```

Comment: have you checked the logs in `kubectl logs`?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I was writing above. The extent of the error is `Killed`, which isn't super helpful. I'll paste in the entirety of the logs above.

Comment: oh, sorry, missed that. You're probably running out of resources and being unceremoniously killed by k8s unless you have good reason to believe you're not using  more than 100 MiB which is all you're allowing your pod.

Comment: Good call on the memory use thing. I somehow missed the out of memory error. Got it running, though the booted kernel still crashes for unexplained reasons, though that may not be a Kubernetes thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a couple of things. First, the memory limit that I set was indeed too low. It needs something in the neighborhood of 2 GB of memory to boot up successfully. Second, It turns out that I hadn't mounted any storage for the notebook files.

Here's the manifest that I came up with that does work. I'm aware that the way I'm mounting storage for the notebooks is perhaps not optimal, but now that I know it's working I feel comfortable tweaking it.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: polynote-config
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: polynote
data:
  config.yml: |-
    listen:
      host: 0.0.0.0

    storage:
      dir: /opt/notebooks
      mounts:
        examples:
          dir: examples
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: polynote
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: polynote
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: polynote
        image: polynote/polynote:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "2000Mi"
            ephemeral-storage: "100Mi"
          requests:
            memory: "2000Mi"
            ephemeral-storage: "100Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8192
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /opt/config/config.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: config.yml
        - name: data
          mountPath: /opt/notebooks/
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: polynote-config
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}
```